# How to troubleshooting a D7 website that doesn't load (Gateway Timeout)

Tags: 7, performance

A website of mine, using D7, suddenly doesn't load. I always receive a Gateway Timeout error.

The strange is that with a ftp client I can browse the website as usual

What are the steps I should follow to troubleshooting this situation?

Comment: If you get a 504, you need to confirm that the problem isn't between you and the webserver first. What do you mean "browse" the site with an ftp-client? Do you mean with a CLI client? Then does your normal client use a proxy that is malfunctioning? Until we can show that this has any kind of connection to Drupal, I think this sounds off-topic.

Comment: I'd look at how much ram you have available too in your php.ini.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Now I better understand the problem. I don't think this post is off-topic, because the problem is anyway related with Drupal (with other cms I didn't have this kind of problem). I've checked the memory limit, is 64M. I've contacted my provider in order to solve the problem and/or increase the memory limit (it's a shared host)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem disabling the Database logging module.

I had the same problem also in another website (D7 + Database logging module, solved disabling the Database logging module)

Hope this helps.